# QCalendarWidget as "Pop-up", not as new Window?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qwidget

I want to create a Settings-Widget, where I can choose a Date.
Because it isn't nice to create 3 QLineEdits to call the QDate-Constructor with QDate(int year, int month, int day), I thought it would be better, if you can push a "show calendar"-Button for example, where you can choose the date.
But I don't want to show this calendar in a new Window, I want to show it as a "Pop-up" (I don't know how to explain this), which you might know for example from the OpenOffice-Settings.
You have any idea how to implement that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an alternate option, have you considered using [`QDateEdit`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qdateedit.html)?  It will allow your users to edit the date in a format that is consistent with the rest of the operating system.

Answer (score 5):

*This is an example of a type popup calendar, you must display the calendar when you press the button on the form. This class can be reutilized in anywhere in your code. In this example this is launched in main function.*

```
 /*
     * DatePopup.h
     *
     *  Created on: Aug 29, 2009
     *      Author: jordenysp
     */

#ifndef DATEPOPUP_H_
#define DATEPOPUP_H_

#include <QDialog>
#include <QDate>
class QCalendarWidget;
class QDialogButtonBox;
class QVBoxLayout;

class DatePopup : public QDialog{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    DatePopup(QWidget *parent=0);
    QDate selectedDate() const;

private:
    QWidget *widget;
    QCalendarWidget *calendarWidget;
    QDialogButtonBox* buttonBox;
    QVBoxLayout *verticalLayout;

};

#endif /* DATEPOPUP_H_ */


/*
 * DatePopup.cpp
 *
 *  Created on: Aug 29, 2009
 *      Author: jordenysp
 */

#include <QtGui>
#include "DatePopup.h"

DatePopup::DatePopup(QWidget *parent)
:QDialog(parent, Qt::Popup)
{
    setSizeGripEnabled(false);
    resize(260, 230);
    widget = new QWidget(this);
    widget->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("widget"));
    widget->setGeometry(QRect(0, 10, 258, 215));

    verticalLayout = new QVBoxLayout(widget);
    verticalLayout->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("verticalLayout"));
    verticalLayout->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);

    calendarWidget = new QCalendarWidget(widget);
    calendarWidget->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("calendarWidget"));

    verticalLayout->addWidget(calendarWidget);

    buttonBox = new QDialogButtonBox(widget);
    buttonBox->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("buttonBox"));
    buttonBox->setOrientation(Qt::Horizontal);
    buttonBox->setStandardButtons(QDialogButtonBox::Cancel|QDialogButtonBox::Ok);

    verticalLayout->addWidget(buttonBox);

    QObject::connect(buttonBox, SIGNAL(accepted()), this, SLOT(accept()));
    QObject::connect(buttonBox, SIGNAL(rejected()), this, SLOT(reject()));
}

QDate DatePopup::selectedDate() const{
    return calendarWidget->selectedDate();
}




#include <QtGui>
#include <QDate>
#include <QApplication>
#include "DatePopup.h"
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    DatePopup popup;

    int result = popup.exec();
    if(result == QDialog::Accepted){
        QDate date = popup.selectedDate();
        std::cout<< date.year() <<std::endl;
        std::cout<< date.month() <<std::endl;
        std::cout<< date.day() <<std::endl;
    }

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: This solution is the one that fits the best to the question as it's really a QCalendarWidget that is brought up